# Nestjs - Mock static function for testing without Module

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, nestjs

I'm currenty trying to write unit tests for my Nestjs Backend. Therefore i use the integrated Jest Framework. Now i have problems with mocking static exports without a certain class.

This is the function i want to test:

```
export const createGetLatestAssetsMetadataQuery = ({
      assetsCatalogueVersion,
      sorting,
    }: AFilter): RequestParams.Search<any> => {
      const match = createCatalogueVersionMatchFactory(VERSION_TIME_STAMP_FIELD)(
        assetsCatalogueVersion
      );
      ...
      return ...
```

This is the function which is called to set the match constant. This method is inside an Util-File but doesn't belong to an Class.

```
export const createCatalogueVersionMatchFactory = (basePath: string) => (
  filter?: string
): { [key: string]: { query: any } } => {
  const result: { [key: string]: any } = {};
  if (filter) {
    const date = parseISO(normalizeDTStringTZ(filter));
    result[basePath] = { query: date };
  }
  return result;
};
```

The Goal is to mock the Return Value of this function.

For functions inside a service i can use

```
jest.spyOn(service, "functionname").mockResolvedValue(returnValue);
```

How can i do it for static functions without a service

Comment: Any good with the above issue?

Comment: I refactored the whole API and now all static methods belong to service-classes. Now i can just inject them and use the jest.spyOn-function